# How to execute a task only once after specified duration in android

Tags: android, timer

I have to execute my piece of code only once after specified duration(lets say after 7 secs). How do I achieve it in android? I used Timer but it is repetitive.
Please help me out with some good example code.

Comment: Use `Handler().postDelayed()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Handler().postDelayed()`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

            //Your task 
          }
        }, 1000);
```

Now here `1000` is the delay in invoking your task in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `Handler`

this way:

```
new Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 500);
```

the `Runnable` should contain the code you want to execute after the timer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the operation to be performed once it is better to use `SharedPreferences`  Here is a piece of code to help you understand

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.apply();
        }
```

Hope this helps

Use a `delay` if you want it to appear after a specified duration